# How to duplicate & flip?

Tags: mirror

I am using blender version 2.70.

I'm trying to mirror another side of the hair but I keep getting a backward mirrored mesh,

I have tried using the SHIFT + D and OBJECT > MIRROR > X GLOBAL or any axis but still getting the same result.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I also tried using mirror modifier but I can't move or separate the "mirrored object", it only show a single vertex.
[image]

Below is another example of what I want vs what I got:

[image]

How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: Make sure your origin is in the correct position. The origin should be in the middle of the hairline.  You can do this in edit mode.  Or the menus have other choices such as move origin to cursor.  The searching mechanism of Blender will help you. This is a 88 second fix.

Comment: Is that real hair or extensions?

Comment: I'm sorry, im new to blender, this is the real hair, not an extensions, idek what's the difference but if you mean by extensions is a mesh i add for the original model? then no i guess.

Comment: im trying to create a custom content for a game, if that helps, idek what's extensions or real hair...? but i made the hair, and the body is from the game